# How to prevent the browser to be redirected to the FORM action after an Ajax submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I'm trying to upload multiple files through a Jquery Ajax submit.

Everything works fine, except after submitting, the browser goes to the url specified in the form, even if I add a `Return False`.

If I use `$("#upload").serialize(),` instead of a `FormData`, it's not re-directed! Here is my Coffeescript code:

```
# Initialization code
$("#upload").submit ->
  ajaxUpload()
  return false

# Handler
ajaxUpload = ->
  fd = new FormData()
  files = $("#uploadFiles")[0].files
  $.each files, (i, file) ->
    fd.append("file" + i, file)
  $.ajax
    type: $("#upload").attr("method"),
    url: $("#upload").attr("action"),
    data: fd,
    # data: $("#upload").serialize(),
    success: (data, text, xhr) ->
      debug "Success: " + JSON.stringify(data)
      loadEventAgain()
    error: (xhr, status) ->
      debug "Error: " + JSON.stringify(xhr)
  alert "done"
  return false
```

Comment: Have you ever tried `e.preventDeafult();`?

Comment: I know JS but not CoffeeScript, so maybe this is a silly question, but what is the last line of that code returning false from? Is it all inside an event handler or something?

Comment: is that the only thing on the page, since ajax essentially reloads part of the page. I am a bit confused as to what your asking?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... the Ajax upload is inside a handler... See revised code above.

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler function you should use `e.preventDefault();`
This prevents the default action which is in your case the form submit.

Comment: But OP is returning false, which is the equivalent of doing both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`...

Comment: Unless the code fails before return false is hit, at which point your page refreshes/loads and you miss any error message that may come back. Return false is such a clumsy ham-fisted way of approaching it and almost always the 'wrong' way to do it in cases like these.

Answer (score 0):

The submit event handler normally gets an event object passed. Perform

```
ev.preventDefault();
//and optionally
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code was failing...
I needed to include:

```
processData: false
contentType: false
```

to prevent JQuery for doing some not-so-desirable magic.